# Почему пагинация в Wordpress добавляет post_name, в результате чего возвращается 404 ошибка?

Tags: wordpress

Вообще немного всё запутано:

Имеем страницу `/articles/` с рабочей пагинацией, и страницу `/multimedia/`, на которой при переходе на страницу пагинации получаем 404 ошибку.

Если скопировать целиком код из `/articles/` в `/multimedia/` - то в `/multimedia/` пагинация всё равно не работает :) Магия какая-то.

Я заметил, что на рабочей странице запрос выглядет так:

> SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.ID = '43') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC

А где пагинация не работает, так:

> SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_name = 'page' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'multimedia' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC

Т. е. к запросу почему-то добавляется условие `wp_posts.post_name = 'page'`

Код везде одинаковый, и сводится к такому виду: (пробовал не перезаписывать глобальную переменную - не помогло)

```
$global_wp_query = $wp_query;
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'post_type' => 'post', // В мультимедиа здесь - multimedia.
// Пробовал добавлять это в запрос - ничего не менялось.
//    'post_name' => '', 
//    'name' => '',
    'paged' => $paged,
]);

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
// Манипуляции с выводом превью
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

// Ну и вывод самой пагинации.
the_posts_pagination([
    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'mid_size'  => 3,
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => '&larr;',
    'next_text' => '&rarr;',
]); $wp_query = $global_wp_query
```

В functions.php никаких манипуляций с пагинацией не производилось, кроме как изменение внешнего вида:

```
add_filter('navigation_markup_template', function ($template, $class) {
    return
        '<nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">'.
        '    <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>'.
        '</nav>';
}, 10, 2);
```

"Настройки постоянных ссылок" сбрасывал; гугление не помогло, всякие советы насчёт количества постов в настройках и прочие - никак не помогают.

Ну и очень интересно, почему один и тот же код на одной странице (`/articles/`) работает корректно, а на другой (`/multimedia/`) - нет :)

Comment: Потому что `/articles/` у вас простая страница с id=43, а `/multimedia/` - архив постов кастомного типа multimedia. Это явно видно из SQL-запроса.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, нет, `/multimedia/` тоже страница с id=39. Они ж обе открываются, и если поменять `paged = 2` в запросе, то отобразиться вторая страница, как и должно.

Comment: Ну либо вы не оттуда запрос привели, либо это все же не страница. Или и страница, и кастомный тип поста - проверьте. SQL запрос второй у вас - не для страницы.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, больше не откуда приводить, это именно та страница) И да, у меня есть кастомный тип поста `multimedia`, только как это связано со страницей? Вывожу всё в `page-multimedia.php`

Comment: Вот не надо так делать, чтобы слаг страницы совпадал с кастомным типом поста. WP этого не любит. Назовите страницу иначе и посмотрите, что получится.